# PHP packet send in perl

Tags: php, perl, sockets

I have this code to send a packet in PHP, and I wanted to know how to do it in perl, I have tried sending via hex data, but it is not working. Here is the PHP code:

```
$sIPAddr = "37.221.175.211";                                                         
$iPort = 7777;                                                               
$sPacket = "";                                                                 
$aIPAddr = explode('.', $sIPAddr);                                              

$sPacket .= "SAMP";                                                           

$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[0]);                                                   
$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[1]);                                                   
$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[2]);                                                   
$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[3]);                                                   

$sPacket .= chr($iPort & 0xFF);                                               
$sPacket .= chr($iPort >> 8 & 0xFF);                                          

$sPacket .= 'c';                                                              


$rSocket = fsockopen('udp://'.$sIPAddr, $iPort, $iError, $sError, 2);           
fwrite($rSocket, $sPacket);

fclose($rSocket);
```

How would I go about doing this in Perl? I want to use a raw socket as well to send it.

This is what I tried, but the server is not replying to it, which makes me think that the data is corrupted somewhere:

```
$packet = Net::RawIP->new({
                        ip => {
                              saddr => $saddr,
                              daddr => $dest,
                              },

                        udp => {
                              source => $rsport,
                              dest => $port,
                              data => "\x53\x41\x4d\x50\x25\xdd\xaf\xd3\x61\x1e\x63", # this is the data from the PHP file in HEX
                              },
                        });
  $packet->send;
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. You said you tried sending hex data. Did you do that in Perl? Please [edit] your question and let us see the code and explain **how** it is not working. Also check out [ask].

Comment: @simbabque Sorry about that, done!

Comment: Comments in Perl are `#`, not `//`. Please do not mock the code in here, but post the real code. Remove stuff you do not like us to see, but try to make it compile please.

Comment: @simbabque Well that is simply the method I am using to send the packet, the rest of the code is not relevant.

Comment: Have you sniffed what this is sending? Since you are using low level functions in PHP, maybe you should try using IO::Socket or [IO::Socket::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::IP)

Comment: @simbabque I am trying to use a raw socket because I need to set the source address.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about `Net::RawIP`, but here's the Perl variant that sends the exact same packet as your PHP code, using `IO::Socket::INET` module. For docs for it, see [https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::INET](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aINET)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;

my $sIPAddr = '37.221.175.211';
my $iPort = 7777;
my $sPacket = 'SAMP' . join( '', map chr,
    split(/\./, $sIPAddr),
    $iPort & 0xFF,
    $iPort >> 8 & 0xFF,
) . 'c';

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Proto    => 'udp',
    PeerPort => $iPort,
    PeerAddr => $sIPAddr,
) or die "Could not create socket: $!\n";

$sock->send( $sPacket );
```